# Breeze theme color problem

Tags: kubuntu, themes, colors, plasma

I recently upgraded Kubuntu to 17.10 Artful using the dark theme, but when I switched to the default breeze theme, this happened( in Plasma 5.11. I used the backports PPA. And no, even in 5.10, the plasma version kubuntu 17.10 ships with, the default theme was messed up as well)
[image: Theme error]

As you can see the pannel and the kickoff menu are all grayed out. They still work, but they are gray. I tried restarting many times but it did not work.

Here are what settings I use:
[image]

[image]

[image]
note:"Briză" means "Breeze"
Am I doing something worng?

Plese help me.

Comment: Have you tried switching back to the dark theme?

Comment: Yes, and it applies corectly, from what I tested, the dark theme applies corectly

Answer (score 0):

White breeze has little bit of transparency (dark version does not) and this is how might look like if this effect does'n work correctly.

1.) Check if your graphics card drivers are installed correctly.

2.) Try disabling all transparency/bloor related effects in Desktop effects in system settings.